# Suspend VBA macro execution until calculations are finished

Tags: vba, calculation

I need to suspend macro execution until all calculations are finished.

I tried using loops with and without `DoEvents` checking `CalculationState` but the loop never ends.

```vb
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: Maybe you have calculations set to manual?

Comment: absolutely NOT, sorry, it's not a trivial question, and no solution on web... nevertheless in my code (plus than 500 pages...) it is proved that code continue its execution using wrong results as calculations are not finished (CALCULATION ARE AUTOMATIC WITH ITAERATION ON)

Comment: Set the calculations to manual then force it to calculate using `YourSheet.Calculate` or if that doesn't work then `Application.CalculateFull` and put a `DoEvents` after it.

Comment: Thanks Simon, already tried as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at handling the application's `AfterCalculate()` event (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.aftercalculate)?

You need to create a class which contains the `Application` object in order to access the handler. You can then call whatever routine you wish from there. If you had more than one routine to call depending on what is being calculated you could set, say, an enum to point to the right procedure. I've called this class *cApp* and skeleton code for that would be:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ProcAferCalcCode
    None
    DeliveryProc
    TimeProc
End Enum

Private WithEvents mApp As Application
Private mProcAfterCalcCode As ProcAferCalcCode

Public Property Let ProcAfterCalc(RHS As ProcAferCalcCode)
    mProcAfterCalcCode = RHS
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    mProcAfterCalcCode = None
    Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    Select Case mProcAfterCalcCode
        Case DeliveryProc
            SetDeliveryOptions
        Case TimeProc
            SetTime
    End Select
End Sub
```

In this example, I have a one-row table that looks like this:
[image]

When the user enters a quantity, and the 'Price' cell calculates (`A * B`), a routine is called that populates the validation list in the 'Delivery' column. When a delivery option is selected, and the 'Cost' cell calculates (`A * D`), a routine is called that retrieves delivery times. It's a trite example, but should give you an idea on how to code it.

Code in a module looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private mApp As cApp

Public Sub RunMe()
    
    Debug.Print "RunMe() called..."
    
    If MsgBox("Ready to enter qty?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Debug.Print "Some user action confirmed."
        Set mApp = New cApp
        mApp.ProcAfterCalc = DeliveryProc
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "RunMe() ended."
    Debug.Print "** No procedure is running **" & vbNewLine
        
End Sub

Public Sub SetDeliveryOptions()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim del As String
    
    Debug.Print "SetDeliveryOptions() called..."
    
    mApp.ProcAfterCalc = None
    
    Set cell = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Price").DataBodyRange
    Debug.Print "Price is " & cell.Value2
    
    'Mimic some task.
    Select Case cell.Value2
        Case 0
            del = vbNullString
        Case Is < 5
            del = "$5 - Standard"
        Case Is < 10
            del = "$5 - Standard, $6 - Express"
        Case Else
            del = "$5 - Standard, $6 - Express, $7 - Next Day"
    End Select
    
    With cell.Offset(, 1)
        .Value = Empty
        With .Validation
            .Delete
            .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, del
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End With
    
    mApp.ProcAfterCalc = TimeProc
    Debug.Print "SetDeliveryOptions() ended."
    Debug.Print "** No procedure is running **" & vbNewLine
    
End Sub

Public Sub SetTime()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim d As Long
    
    Debug.Print "SetTime() called..."
    
    mApp.ProcAfterCalc = None
    
    Set cell = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Delivery").DataBodyRange
    Debug.Print "Delivery Option is " & cell.Value
    
    'Mimic some other task.
    Select Case cell.Value2
        Case Is = "$5 - Standard"
            d = Int((10 - 5 + 1) * Rnd + 5)
        Case Is = "$6 - Express"
            d = Int((5 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        Case Is = "$7 - Next Day"
            d = 1
        Case Else
            d = 0
    End Select
    
    cell.Offset(, 1) = d
    
    Debug.Print "SetTime() ended."
    Debug.Print "** No procedure is running **" & vbNewLine
    
End Sub
```

The immediate window outputs the following:

> RunMe() called...
>
> Some user action confirmed.
>
> RunMe() ended.
>
> ** No procedure is running **
>
> SetDeliveryOptions() called...
>
> Price is 25
>
> SetDeliveryOptions() ended.
>
> ** No procedure is running **
>
> SetTime() called...
>
> Delivery Option is $7 - Next Day
>
> SetTime() ended.
>
> ** No procedure is running **

Comment: Dear Ambie, pretty CLEAR despite complex. I tried immediately with a dumby excel file, but it looks like capp is not defined, and I have not been able to fix the issue as I am not that practical with Class definition. Could you explain how could I correct? Thanks

Comment: Dear Ambie, I finally was able to run your example: GREAT, I just forgot to give the name (cApp) to the class module, sorry. Now I will move "your" solution to the real workbook.... THANKS!!!

Comment: Sorry Ambie, I have got a different result, as it looks like the class call of routimes happen at the second time i launch the RUN routine...

RunMe2() called...
RunMe2() ended.
** No procedure is running **

SetDeliveryOptions() called...
SetDeliveryOptions() ended.
** No procedure is running **

RunMe2() called...
SetTime() called...
SetTime() ended.
** No procedure is running **

RunMe2() ended.
** No procedure is running **

Comment: @roberto It's impossible to say what might be going on there without seeing your code. Suggest you post a new question, but sounds as if the class isn't being initialised or has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

What state is it in?

- List item xlCalculating  1   Calculations in process.
- List item xlDone 0   Calculations complete.
- List item xlPending  2   Changes that trigger calculation have been made, but a recalculation has not yet been performed.

It might help you determine what is happening on your worksheets.

Comment: Always status 2 (pending)